# ASP.NET Routing Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Why is this:

```
http://MySite.com/Project/24/Search/32/Edit/49
```

preferred over this?

```
http://MySite.com/Project/24?Search=32&Edit=49
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure where your premise is coming from? It looks like an artificial example, which makes it hard to comment on.

A better comparison would be something like:

```
http://MySite.com/Project/24/Members/Edit
```

As opposed to:

```
http://MySite.com/Projects.aspx?id=24&section=Members&action=Edit
```

Where, among other things, the hierarchy of entities is immediately obvious from the first example (ie, a Project contains Members). It also suggests that you can use other URLs that contain similar structures to the first (ie, `/Projects/24` and `/Projects/24/Members`), so in that sense it's more concise.

If it comes down to actions that have a variable number of parameters, such as searching, then it's totally fine to use URL parameters as this will give you more flexibility, eg:

```
http://MySite.com/Projects/Search?name=KillerApp&type=NET
```

You could construct a URL using the first style, but you don't really gain anything, and managing the route could add unnecessary overhead:

```
http://MySite.com/Projects/Search/name/KillerApp/type/NET
```

I would argue that this (or any similar construction, eg if you removed the param names) suffers from an artificial hierarchy - the action in this case is really Search, and everything else is just a parameter of the Search, so it's in the same hierarchy, not some "sub" hierarchy.

Comment: It's a real example.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080415/custom-routing-rules-e-g-www-app-com-project-35-search-89-edit-89/1080467#1080467

Comment: Wow - you're right - in so much as someone does want to construct their URLs like that anyway! I really think the poster doesn't want to do that though - unless I really misunderstand the domain. I don't get why a search would have an id. Or why it would be part of a particular project. Or why you'd want to edit it. But I'm probably missing something. In any case, I think your second suggestion on that topic is probably what they're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a fair comparison. The style allows you to drop the GET parameter names, so the routed one should read something like

```
http://MySite.com/Project/24/32/49
```

It's really an aesthetic improvement, though -- it's both neater-looking, and easier to type or read out to someone.

Comment: The only problem with this syntax is that it requires every parameter.  If one of the parameters is omitted, the routing will get confused.

Answer (score 3):

Its mostly a human readability issue, although (since most search engine ranking algorithms are not publically disclosed), it is believed to have SEO value as well.

Answer (score 1):

In the example case, it may not be any better.  But it's a [Search Engine Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) in general.  Here are some [SEO best practices](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-best-practices-for-url-structure/7216/) -- from that article ...

> Ideally, the URL structures should be
>   static, and reveal what the page is
>   about. A simple and clear URL
>   structure is much easier for both
>   search engine spiders and human
>   beings.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to remember as well.  It's easier for a user to remember /Employee/1 to get the information for employee #1 rather than understand a querystring.  Not a reason to use it but I think its a small improvement.